# AES256 encryption & decryption with PKCS5PADDING in iOS

Tags: ios, encryption

On iOS native front, AES 256 libraries supports PKCS7PADDING.   The CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor class supports only PKCS7PADDING and ECBMode.

I have already referred following link:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64176
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding

How to achieve AES256 with PKCS5PADDING?

Comment: PKCS5Padding and PKCS7Padding are the same thing.  Don't use ECB mode.

Comment: assuming they dont make a difference, yet my decryption is failing.

Comment: There is no standard for encoding encrypted data. You need to know precisely how the encryptor generated its key (if it stretched a password into a key), what mode it used, what IV it used, whether there is an HMAC, whether there is header or trailing information, how it encoded the output (raw bytes, base64, hex), etc. There are a lot of different ways to use AES, and there is no single standard widely used across all systems. Just knowing the key length and the padding is not enough to write a decryptor.

Answer (score 1):

1. The default CommonCrypto mode for AES is CBC mode.

The cloest documentation I can find is in the CommonCryptor.h header:

> Initialization vector, optional. Used for Cipher Block Chaining (CBC) mode. If present, must be the same length as the selected algorithm's block size. If **CBC mode is selected (by the absence of any mode bits in the options flags)** and no IV is present, a NULL (all zeroes) IV will be used. This is ignored if ECB mode is used or if a stream cipher algorithm is selected.

2. [PKCS#7 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS7) is the correct padding for AES and is a superset of PKCS#5 padding.

> PKCS#5 padding is identical to PKCS#7 padding, except that it has only been defined for block ciphers that use a 64-bit (8 byte) block size. In practice the two can be used interchangeably.

Background: Many AES implementations use PKCS#5 because it was used prior to AES and the implementators were to lazy to also define PKCS#7 for use with AES and just used the PKCS#5 naming. In general actual implementation of PKCS#5 fully support PKCS#7.